# Placing planter on rooftop

Tags: roof

Our house has a flat rooftop. I'd like to a planter box up there 2x3 ft, 15 inches deep. Online calculators say it would take 650 lbs (~300 kg) of soil to fill it.

Would it be safe to have this much weight on the rooftop? It's a 2-storey wood frame house.

Comment: Depends on how the roof is made. I would allow for possibly 800 lbs in case you have a lot of rain

Answer (score 1):

No your roof is not strong enough for this. Most roofs are designed to take the area's snow load which is USUALLY between 20-50psf. Even if the space was a porch or occupiable roof it'd only be designed for 40psf on top of that. What you have is 108 psf, there's no way you're roof was designed for this.